# Is this the correct way to union VBA range into one?

Tags: excel, vba, range, union

Im trying to export 4 columns into one .csv file. Therefore I want to combine all 4 columns into one range and export this range. Somehow rng only has one column. Why?

```
Set rng = Application.Union(Range("Berechnung!$A$10811:$A$39611"),Range("Berechnung!$BA$10811:$BC$39611"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need `Application`

Comment: "Somehow my final range only has one column"... what's the rest of your code? Are you using `.Columns`? If you are, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columns): When applied to a Range object that is a multiple-area selection, this property returns columns from only the first area of the range

Comment: You may want to provide more details and possibly the shape of the dataset you want to export to the CSV.

Comment: Yes, Im using .columns to print all columns to the .csv:

`For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            str = str & rng(i, j).Value & " ,"
        Next
        Print #fNum, Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
        str = ""
    Next`

Comment: You have to loop over the `Areas` of `rng`.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of UNION is fine, but now you must account for the fact that the range has more than one area.

This answer uses YOUR code and extends it to work with the areas in the disjointed range.

```
Set rng = Union(Range("Berechnung!$A$10811:$A$39611"),Range("Berechnung!$BA$10811:$BC$39611"))

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For a = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Areas(a).Columns.Count
            str = str & rng.Areas(a)(i, j).Value & " ,"
        Next
    Next
    Print #fNum, Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
    str = ""
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a disjoint range.  It is not easy to count the number of columns in this case.  For example:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, rTot As Range, Column As Variant
    Dim kount As Long
    Set r1 = Range("A1:A10")
    Set r2 = Range("D1:E10")
    Set rTot = Union(r1, r2)

    MsgBox rTot.Columns.Count

    kount = 0
    For Each Column In rTot.Columns
        kount = kount + 1
    Next Column

    MsgBox kount
End Sub
```

The first `MsgBox` will report *1*, the second `MsgBox` will report *3*.

Comment: Instead of looping, I think this would be better `MsgBox Intersect(rTot, rTot(1, 1).EntireRow).Cells.Count`

Comment: @YasserKhalil  **GREAT IDEA** .................I can use this suggestion myself.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub MyExportCsv()

    Const START_ROW = 10811
    Const END_ROW = 39611
    Const CSV_FILE = "export.csv"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, str As String, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, count As Long

    Dim oFSO As Object, oFS As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFS = oFSO.CreateTextFile(CSV_FILE)

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For i = START_ROW To END_ROW

        str = ws.Range("A" & i)
        Set rng = ws.Range("BA" & i & ":BC" & i)
        For Each cell In rng
           str = str & " ," & cell.Value
        Next
        oFS.writeline str
        count = count + 1

    Next
    oFS.Close

    MsgBox count & " records written to " & CSV_FILE, vbInformation, "Finished"

End Sub
```

Comment: @Excel  4 columns A, BA, BB, BC isn't that it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a procedure that creates an array and converts it to csv as a parameter.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim xcsvFile As String
    Dim vDB1 As Variant, vDB2 As Variant, vDB() As Variant
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, j As Integer
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    xcsvFile = CurDir & "\" & Ws.Name & ".csv"


    vDB1 = Range("Berechnung!$A$10811:$A$39611")
    vDB2 = Range("Berechnung!$BA$10811:$BC$39611")


    r = UBound(vDB1, 1)
    ReDim vDB(1 To r, 1 To 4)
    For i = 1 To r
        vDB(i, 1) = vDB1(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To 3
            vDB(i, j + 1) = vDB2(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    TransToCSV xcsvFile, vDB
    MsgBox ("Files Saved Successfully")
End Sub

Sub TransToCSV(myfile As String, vDB As Variant)

    Dim vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim objStream
    Dim strTxt As String

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
        vTxt(n) = Join(vR, ",")
    Next i
    strTxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
         .Open
        .WriteText strTxt
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```